# How can I implement jQuery or CSS3 to animate these, slides to give the effect of them moving from left to right.

Tags: jquery, css

I have these slides I want to come in from the left or right.

I have tab buttons that equal the number of tabs.

I've given them unique data attributes:

```
 var i = 0;
 $('.tab').each(function () {
     $(this).attr('dt', i);
     i++;
 });
```

My slides also have unique attributes so I can compare the tab and slide attributes to test whether I want the slide to come in from the left or right with this:

```
$('.tab').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('dt');
    var a = $('.profile:first-child').attr('data');
    if (a > id) {
        $('[data='+id+']').prependTo('#meet-the-team-window');
        console.log('lower');
    } else if (a == id) {
        $('[data='+id+']').prependTo('#meet-the-team-window');
        console.log('equal');
    } else {
        $('[data='+id+']').prependTo('#meet-the-team-window');
        console.log('higher');
    }
});
```

If I get the `console.log` "lower" then I want the slide to come in from the left.

If I get the `console.log` "higher" then I want the slide to come in from the right.

Other than simple `fadeIn` techniques, I have so far been unsuccessful in getting the slide in effect.

To give you an idea of how these slides are working here's some of my CSS:

```
#window {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width:320px;
    height:auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#container {
    width:1280px;
    position: relative;
}
.slide {
    float:left;
    display: block;
    width:320px;
    height:auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The `#container` here equals the width of the total number of slides and is nested inside the `#window` which has a width of a single slide, 320px;. Each slide is then floated left.

If you look at my jQuery you can see all I'm doing is prepending my slides to the front, so far this works like a charm but it looks far too boring

How can I use jQuery or even CSS3 to get a slide in effect?

Comment: Typically what I do for slides is display them `inline-block` inside a wrapper, which is inside a frame. I `position:relative` the wrapper, and move it `left` positively or negatively. If you set up a JSFiddle with what you've got now, we can take a look at specifics.

Comment: ah, thanks, I'll try the inline-block method.